# Closed form solution for Gradient Descent step - from B and V

Tags: convex-optimization, gradient-descent

I am trying to derive the Gradient descent step x<sup>k</sup> also given as excercise 9.6 in the book - Convex Optimisation - B and V . The G.D step is found for the following function . 
$$f(x) =\frac{(x_{1}^{2}+\gamma x_{2}^{2})}{2}$$

The solution for the problem is : 
$$x_{1}^{k} = \frac{\gamma(\gamma-1)^{k}}{(\gamma + 1)^{k}} , x_{2}^{k} = \frac{(-(\gamma-1))^{k}}{(\gamma + 1)^{k}}$$

Solution manual  of the book says something like this : . 
For $K = 0$ , we have  the starting points $x^{0} =\{\gamma,1\}$ .
My first question is how did we chose the intial points to be $x^{0} =\{\gamma,1\}$  ?
Further  he writes : 
$$x^{k} -t\Delta(f(x^{k})) =$$ \begin{bmatrix}(1-t)x_{1}^{k}\\(1-\gamma t)x_{2}^{k}\end{bmatrix} . 
This is clear, but the solution further says that the above is equal to : 
$$
\frac{(\gamma -1)^{k} }{(\gamma +1)^{k}}  \begin{bmatrix}(1-t)\gamma^{k}\\(-1)^{k} \end{bmatrix} 
$$

How did we get here ?

Comment: perhaps you could go over your previous question and mark it as answered, if any of the answers was satisfactory

Comment: Did that, new to this website. Thanks for letting me know.